# Android Search History Statistics

Tags: android, search, google-play

Does Google (or any android marketplace) publish their search statistics: e.g. how many users searched for "angry birds" in the last month?  Is there a Google Trends for the Android Marketplace?

Google provides general search analysis within their Adwords and Google Trends offering, but cannot see it for Android Marketplace.